# Confusion with pointers in problem related to linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am currently learning linked list and have the below class and function to add an item to a linked list

```
#include <iostream>

class Node{
  public:
  int data;
  Node *next;

};

class LinkedList{
  private:
  Node *head;
    public:
    LinkedList(){
      head=NULL; //at start ll is empty
    }




  void add(int d){
     Node *node=new Node();

    node->data=d;
    node->next=NULL;

    if(head==NULL){
      head=node;  
    }else{

           Node *lastnode=head;
            for(;lastnode->next!=NULL;lastnode=lastnode->next){

            }

            lastnode->next=node;
          }

  }
```

In the line   `Node *lastnode=head;` why is lastnode pointing towards address of head? Shouldn't it be like this:

```
Node *lastnode;
lastnode=head;
```

I am totally confused with this. can anyone explain me the add function wrt to pointers

Comment: `Shouldnd it be

   Node *lastnode=head;
   lastnode=head;` What, why? Initialize it to `head` and immediately assign `head` to it again?

Comment: Why does every CS school teach about linked lists? I never had to use one...

Comment: sorry edited the question to reflect it

Comment: `Node *lastnode=head;` and `Node *lastnode;
   lastnode=head;` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: when we remove * symbol dont we refer it to the address we want to point to ??

Comment: You are confusing language syntax/semantics with that of linked list. Try to learn one thing at a time rather than getting confused by both.

Comment: anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a good book which explains data structures. I'll try to answer your query as best as I can.

```
Node *lastnode=head;
for(;lastnode->next!=NULL;lastnode=lastnode->next){
}
lastnode->next=node;
```

This code grabs the head node through `lastnode = head`. Then it proceeds to walk the list and read the end. It checks for end by verify `lastnode -> next` is null. It moves to the next node through `lastnode = lastnode -> next`.

Since your `add` function appears to be appending and you don't have any tail pointer, it must walk the entire list each time.

P.S.: Pay attention about how you format code. If you can't format it properly, there's no point wasting your time in this field.

Comment: Again, read a good book about C++. This line can be broken into a declaration and assignment like `Node* lastnode;` and `lastnode = head;`. That `*` means `lastnode` is a pointer.